# Error: "Channel not in Stasis application" when adding channel to a bridge

Tags: asterisk, voip

I'm working with Asterisk ARI. When I create channels via ARI, I specify application name and I can add those channels to a bridge with no problem. But when I use other client (like Zoiper) to make calls, and try to add those channels to a bridge, I get an error "Channel not in Stasis application". I am not sure what is Stasis, I followed [this article](http://astrecipes.net/index.php?q=astrecipes/getting%20started%20with%20ari) and put the following in extensions conf file, but it still doesn't work:

```
same => n,Stasis(myApp)
same => n,Hangup()
```

So, what is a stasis app and how can I be able to bridge channels which are created outside of ARI?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge already bridged calls

You can bridge by AMI calls which are set to MOH or AsyncAGI applications.

Comment: That is not what the error is, and - in fact - you can use the addChannel operation on a bridge resource to add a channel that is in another bridge.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform operations on channels that are not in a Stasis application. This is a safety mechanism: a [Stasis application](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Introduction+to+ARI+and+Channels#IntroductiontoARIandChannels-ChannelsinaStasisApplication) hands complete control of the channel over to your external application to control. Channels in dialplan are not in that state, and many operations on a channel that are possible through ARI would cause problems (read: crash) if they were performed on a channel in dialplan.

You'll need to place the channel into the Stasis dialplan application to control it using the [/channels](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API) resource.

Comment: can you point to where we can read about how to put channels in a stasis? also, 1 question: can we automatically put every channel in a stasis? so that it doesn't matter from were the calls originate? thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. The Stasis dialplan application is how you put channels into Stasis (which is somewhat self referential).

2. You can do that simply by using a catch-all pattern matching extension, and dropping all channels into the Stasis dialplan application. Today, that's the only way to do that.

Comment: can you give any reference links or articles, thanks in Advance